# Block not show frm_xxx

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i have a form which have multible blocks 
A,B,C
frm_xxx not shown on block A but it is shown on the other blocks .
for example : if i fill a date item on block B with Vvv this will show frm_50936 to fill with correct format  but 
in block A the frm_xxx not appear at all but suspend to fill with correct format.

what is the problem?

Comment: From my point of view, problem is that I don't understand what you are saying. Could you, please, explain it once again? What kind of field is the one in block A (the one that doesn't raise the error)? What did you put into it? What does "suspend to fill with correct format" mean? Post a form screenshot as well (or, even better, two of them - one that shows what's going on in block A, and another on other block(s)).

Comment: @Littlefoot ok ,the problem is that block A doesn't show frm_xxx on its own items  regardless type of items or fields

Comment: Is there any trigger that prevents it? Did you run form in debug mode and check what's going on?

Comment: i will check that ,but what will  makes all frm_xxx messages not shown ??

Comment: ON-ERROR and/or ON-MESSAGE trigger might.

Comment: @Littlefoot hi ,i have on-error trigger built on block A level ,when I deleted it , the problem solved ! but i have a condition in it so why all frm-xxx messages not shown

Comment: perhaps `:system.message_level` is set somewhere in the form.

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot this is the code in th on-error trigger and it didn't enter the condition.

```
declare
lnum number:=error_code;
ltxt varchar2(300):=error_text;
ltype varchar2 (3):=error_type
begin
if ltype='FRM' and lnum=40654  then
null; end if ;end;
```

Comment: this is not an answer, but might be an edit which should be added to the question.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it explicitly ignores FRM-40654, and implicitly ignores everything else. If you don't somehow re-raise the errors you DO want to see, this code will cause them to be discarded.